# MySQL - Getting All Employees First Punch in time and Last Punch in time within Date Range

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I need to find All Employees First Login time and Last Logout time within Date Range. So far I tried different approach with Group by clause but not able to get what I want I tried this query

```
   SELECT p1.EmpName, p1.LogDate,  
          (SELECT MIN(LogTime) 
     FROM log as p2 
    WHERE p2.EmpName=p1.EmpName 
 GROUP BY p2.EmpName) as login, 
          (SELECT MAX(LogTime) 
             FROM log as p2 
            WHERE p2.EmpName=p1.EmpName 
         GROUP BY p2.EmpName) as logout, 
                  LogID from log as p1 
            WHERE LogDate 
          BETWEEN '2017-08-05 00:00:00' 
              AND '2017-08-010 00:00:00' 
         GROUP BY SrNo
```

I achieved what I was looking for But this gives me duplicate results. Here is actual table of log[image]

Here is what I have achieved so far[image]

I want the same result as 2nd picture but without duplicated rows. I found that OVER & PARTITION are not available in MySQL which makes it more difficult. I'm not good with selfjoins.

Comment: Did you try to use mysql `distinct` function ? This will help for duplicates and will only select one

Comment: If I use it on EmpName coloumn with DISTINCT than It removes the rows from different Date (same EmpName) as well and gives me row for one particular date only.

Comment: In that case you can switch to group by in combination of order by

Comment: I need each EmpName for each and Every Date with last and first LogTime of that date...

Comment: Could you provide us the desired result ?

Comment: Group By is not the solution I believe.. Group by will remove Employee login for different date as well..

Comment: For given date range Every Employees first login time and last login time

Comment: I have already used group by EmpName it removes rows from different dates as well.

Comment: There are more than 400 rows I can't include all of them... It is Employee Timesheet application.. Where Employee swipes card whenever he enters or goes outside of the office.. so for same day there will be multiple LogTimes for every employee.. I need to find first logTime for the day and Last logTime for the day for every employee for selected date range

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your query into another `SELECT` and apply a `GROUP BY` on it, e.g.:

```
SELECT a.EmpName, a.LogDate, a.login, a.logout, a.logID
FROM (
  SELECT p1.EmpName, p1.LogDate,  
    (SELECT MIN(LogTime) FROM log as p2 WHERE p2.EmpName=p1.EmpName Group by p2.EmpName) as login, 
    (SELECT MAX(LogTime) FROM log as p2 WHERE p2.EmpName=p1.EmpName Group by p2.EmpName) as logout, LogID 
  FROM log as p1 WHERE LogDate Between '2017-08-05 00:00:00' AND '2017-08-010 
  00:00:00' group by SrNo
) a
GROUP BY a.EmpName, a.LogDate, a.login, a.logout, a.logID
```

Comment: 4 select statement along with 4 group by will take lot of time to execute considering 400 employees.

Comment: There are more than 400 rows, so should be fine.